# Replace multiple strings in a single pass

Tags: bash, sed, awk, string, replace

I'm looking for a way to replace placeholder strings in a template file with concrete values, with common Unix tools (bash, sed, awk, maybe perl). It is important that the replacement is done in a single pass, that is, what is already scanned/replaced must not be considered for another replacement. For example, these two attempts fail:

```
echo "AB" | awk '{gsub("A","B");gsub("B","A");print}'
>> AA

echo "AB" | sed 's/A/B/g;s/B/A/g'
>> AA
```

The correct result in this case is of course BA.

In general, the solution should be equivalent to scanning the input left-to-right for a longest match to one of the given replacement strings, and for each match, performing a replacement and continuing from that point on in the input (none of the already read input nor the replacements performed should be considered for matches). Actually, the details don't matter, just that the results of the replacement are never considered for another replacement, in whole or in part.

**NOTE** I am only looking for correct generic solutions. Please do not propose solutions which fail for certain inputs (input files, search and replace pairs), however unlikely they may seem.

Comment: I assume they're longer than one character? For this you could use `tr AB BA`.

Comment: Yes, they're longer than one character. Assume that both the match and replacement strings are arbitrary strings.

Comment: `echo "AB"|sed 's/A/!!TMP!!/g;s/B/A/g;s/!!TMP!!/B/g'`

Comment: @bersch It's not correct with respect to all possible inputs.

Comment: In that case you need to make your question more precise to make clear how general the patterns and inputs can be.

Comment: And frankly, I wouldn't be surprised if someone considered your note a bit rude.

Comment: How do you expect to "only get correct solutions" when you haven't provided sample input or output?

Comment: @peterph I was assuming that unless stated otherwise solutions need to be generic and correct. For some reason unknown to me people in Unix circles like half-solutions a lot.

Comment: Well, you're not going to make it any better like this... Back to the point: specify how general outputs and inputs can be.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to do it exactly as you are describing it - parse from the beginning and replace as you go - i.e. not with regular expressions.

Comment: Any chance a [mail merge](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41027/22886) could do the job?

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak: there is probably no better solution with `sed`. BTW: you can parse the string with a simple for loop. Nobody answered so far, perhaps because it is really not a problem.

Comment: This is a fair question, but the answer is *you need a state machine parser*, which is what rici's answer provides (in true hacker style, I think).  In other words, you are underestimating the complexity of the task, ala "I want to generically parse (HT|X)ML with regular expressions" -> The answer is NO.  You **cannot** (just) use sed.  You **cannot** (just) use awk.  AFAIK there is no existing tool that will do this out of the box.  Sans rici's exploit, you'd need to write some code.

Comment: @goldilocks - there are lots of little tools that can do it combination. You probably could do it with *just* `sed` if you used a couple instances, the `l` function, and a couple of pipes between them. But I do it below with `od` and `sed` - well, and `xargs` and `printf`... In fairness, though, it is ASCII specific. `dc` could do this as well, I think, but with the same limitation.

Comment: regarding @goldilocks' comment - obligatory reference to the [canonical SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is in place.

Answer (score 12):

OK, a general solution. The following bash function requires `2k` arguments; each pair consists of a placeholder and a replacement. It's up to you to quote the strings appropriately to pass them into the function. If the number of arguments is odd, an implicit empty argument will be added, which will effectively delete occurrences of the last placeholder.

Neither placeholders nor replacements may contain NUL characters, but you may use standard C `\`-escapes such as `\0` if you need `NUL`s (and consequently you are required to write `\\` if you want a `\`).

It requires the standard build tools which should be present on a posix-like system (lex and cc).

```
replaceholder() {
  local dir=$(mktemp -d)
  ( cd "$dir"
    { printf %s\\n "%option 8bit noyywrap nounput" "%%"
      printf '"%s" {fputs("%s", yyout);}\n' "${@//\"/\\\"}"
      printf %s\\n "%%" "int main(int argc, char** argv) { return yylex(); }"
    } | lex && cc lex.yy.c
  ) && "$dir"/a.out
  rm -fR "$dir"
}
```

We assume that `\` is already escaped if necessary in the arguments
but we need to escape double quotes, if present. That's what the
second argument to the second printf does. Since the `lex` default action is `ECHO`, we don't need to worry about it.

Example run (with timings for the skeptical; it's just a cheap-o commodity laptop):

```
$ time echo AB | replaceholder A B B A
BA

real    0m0.128s
user    0m0.106s
sys     0m0.042s
$ time printf %s\\n AB{0000..9999} | replaceholder A B B A > /dev/null

real    0m0.118s
user    0m0.117s
sys     0m0.043s
```

For larger inputs it might be useful to provide an optimization flag to `cc`, and for current Posix compatibility, it would be better to use `c99`. An even more ambitious implementation might try to cache the generated executables instead of generating them each time, but they're not exactly expensive to generate.

**Edit**

If you have [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/), you can avoid the hassle of creating a temporary directory, and enjoy the faster compile time which will help on normal sized inputs:

```
treplaceholder () { 
  tcc -run <(
  {
    printf %s\\n "%option 8bit noyywrap nounput" "%%"
    printf '"%s" {fputs("%s", yyout);}\n' "${@//\"/\\\"}"
    printf %s\\n "%%" "int main(int argc, char** argv) { return yylex(); }"
  } | lex -t)
}

$ time printf %s\\n AB{0000..9999} | treplaceholder A B B A > /dev/null

real    0m0.039s
user    0m0.041s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a joke or not ;)

Comment: @ambrozbizjak: It works, it's quick for large inputs and acceptably fast for small inputs. It might not use the tools you were thinking of but they are standard tools. Why would it be a joke?

Comment: +1 For not being a joke! :D

Comment: That would be POSIX portable like `fn() { tcc ; } <<CODE\n$(gen code)\nCODE\n`. Can I ask though - this an awesome answer and I upvoted it as soon as I read it - but I don't understand what's happening to the shell array? What does `"${@//\"/\\\"}"` this do?

Comment: @mikeserv: «For each argument as a quoted value ("$@"), replace all (//) occurrences of a quote (\") with (/) a backslash (\\\) followed by a quote (\")». See Parameter expansion in the bash manual.

Comment: I do generally understand parameter expansion - just not too familiar with `bash`isms. I didn't think you could do any direct expansions on the shell array itself. At least the spec calls its behavior *unspecified.*

Comment: @mikeserv. You could call it bashism, I guess. It also works with ksh and zsh, so it's pretty widespread. I don't know which one had it first.

Comment: I think you're right - `ksh` I think. I'm bigot, I guess. Sorry. I'm just not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'STRING1STRING1\n\nSTRING2STRING1\nSTRING2\n' |
od -A n -t c -v -w1 |
sed 's/ \{1,3\}//;s/\\$/&&/;H;s/.*//;x
     /\nS\nT\nR\nI\nN\nG\n1/s//STRING2/
     /\nS\nT\nR\nI\nN\nG\n2/s//STRING1/
     /\\n/!{x;d};s/\n//g;s/./\\&/g' |
     xargs printf %b

###OUTPUT###

STRING2STRING2

STRING1STRING2
STRING1
```

Something like this will always replace each occurrence of your target strings only once as they occur in `sed`'s in stream at one bite per line. This is the fastest way I can imagine you'd do it. Then again, I don't write C. But this *does* reliably handle null delimiters if you wish it. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137460/52934) for how it works. This has no problems with any contained special shell characters or similar - but it *is* ASCII  locale specific, or, in other words, `od` will not output multi-byte characters on the same line and will only do one per. If this is a problem you'll want to add in `iconv`.

Comment: +1 Why do you say it only replaces "the earliest occurrence of your target strings"? In the output it looks as if it replaces all of them.  I'm not asking to see it, but could this be done this way without hardcoding the values?

Comment: @goldilocks - Yes - but only as soon as they occur. Maybe I should reword that. And yeah - you could just add a middle `sed` in and save up to a null or something then have that `sed` write this one's script; or put it in a shell function and give it values at one bite per line like `"/$1/"`...`"/$2/"` - maybe I'll write those functions too...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the case where the placeholders are `PLACE1`, `PLACE2` and `PLA`. `PLA` always wins. OP says: "equivalent to scanning the input left-to-right for a *longest match* to one of the given replacement strings" (emphasis added)

Comment: @rici - thanks. Then I will have to do the null delimiters. Back in a flash.

Comment: @rici - I was just about to post another version, that will handle what you describe, but looking at it again and I don't think I should. He says longest for *one* of the given replacement strings. This does that. There's no indication that one string is a subset of another, only that the replaced value may be. I also don't think iterating over a list is a valid way to solve the problem. Given the problem as I understand it, this is a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution. Even if some stated it is not possible, I found one but in general a simple match and replace is not possible and even it gets worse because of the backtracking of a NFA the result can be unexpected.

In general, and this must be said, the problem yelds different results which depend on the order and length of the replacement tuples. i.e.:

```
A B
AA CC
```

and the input `AAA` results in `BBB` or `CCB`.

Here the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$v='if (0) {} ';
while (($a,$b)=split /\s+/, <DATA>) {
  $k.=$a.'|';
  $v.='elsif ($& eq \''.$a.'\') {print \''.$b.'\'} ';
}
$k.='.';
$v.='else {print $&;}';

eval "
while (<>) {
  \$_ =~ s/($k)/{$v}/geco;
}";  
print "\n";


__DATA__
A    B
B    A
abba baab
baab abbc
abbc aaba
```

Checkerbunny:

```
$ echo 'ABBabbaBBbaabAAabbc'|perl script
$ BAAbaabAAabbcBBaaba
```